# Regenesis - why is it not widely available?

Tags: distribution, regenesis

Series 1 of the Canadian series [Regenesis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0429422/) seems widely available worldwide. Series 2 seems to be more rare but none the less, available.

However, by the time we get to series 3 & 4 it seems to be available no where but Japan. Not even in Canada where it was made!

I'm in the UK so the Japanese DVD region (2) matches the UK however the box sets cost £60 odd which is a bit extreme for a 7-8 year old series.

[JP series 3](http://www.amazon.co.jp/Re-Genesis-3-DVD-BOX-%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8/dp/B001CS1X64/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1427124625&sr=8-2&keywords=regenesis)

[JP series 4](http://www.amazon.co.jp/Re-Genesis-4-DVD-BOX-%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8/dp/B003V4EKJ4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1427124625&sr=8-1&keywords=regenesis)

Why is this series not more widely available? Why only in Japan?

(It's also not available on Amazon Prime, Amazon by post or Netflix in the UK)

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is on-topic, but will leave it to someone else to decide.

Comment: It is available on Hulu. (Though technically Hulu is US only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be hope yet.  If they continue to release them as the bolded text below implies, they may get to seasons 3 and 4 later this year... though the source for the info links to the German Amazon page, but the discs are in English and German... also, the release date has been pushed back to April 3rd and it will also be [available on DVD](http://www.amazon.de/ReGenesis-Season-2-4-DVDs/dp/B00TQJ5J7K/ref=sr_1_2?s=dvd&ie=UTF8&qid=1427211672&sr=1-2&keywords=ReGenesis%20-%20Season%202).

From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReGenesis) page:

> On November 11, 2008 Season 1 was released in North America on DVD by Entertainment One. The four-disc set includes all 13 first season episodes presented in a letterbox format. Special features include a making of, photo gallery, and "The Facts Behind the Fiction" (the white papers published by the Ontario Genomics Institute). Shaftesbury Films claimed that Seasons 2, 3 and 4 would follow throughout 2009 and 2010, but as of February 2013 no such releases have emerged.
>
> The first season has also been released in the UK through Universal Studios UK. The second season was later released to European countries by Buena Vista Home Entertainment, though it was presented in a Pan and Scan format. Seasons 3 and 4 have been released on DVD in Japan—Season 3 in letterbox format and Season 4 in 16:9 widescreen. The Japanese Season 3 boxset includes a 20-minute Making Of video and the Season 4 boxset a 20-minute Peter Outerbridge interview titled "Pretending With Conviction".
>
> On January 30, 2015 Season 1 was released in Europe on Blu-ray by Entertainment One. The three-disc set includes all 13 first season episodes. **Season 2 will be released on [Blu-ray March 23, 2015](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00TQJ5J0C).**

Comment: That's good information, but technically not an answer to the question. I'm afraid though the answer simply is: Because they did not think it was profitable.

Comment: Yeah, I know. @NapoleonWilson and I have already chatted about that. Would it sit better with you if I prefaced it with "not an answer but..."

Comment: I really don't mind, just thought it was worth mentioning. ;)

Answer (score 3):

There was a time that ReGenesis, complete, was available to stream on Hulu. Perhaps it is still. I would check other such services as well.

When all else fails, there is the, ahem, backdoor method, which is how I saw it while the episodes were brand new and not yet being broadcast in the US. It's nothing I'd advocate for material that's commercially available, but there's a great deal of industry "look the other way" for non-local content of a certain vintage that has never had a commercial release. (That's not an assumption. I've seen posts from, and heard interviews with, show runners who run the gamut from wryly writing that they're putting their fingers in their ears and going LA-LA-LA to actively encouraging you to watch the show any way you can. Since in both cited examples the responses were public — official bulletin board and open podcast — I suppose it's even safe to name the shows, which at the time did not have DVD releases: THE COLLECTOR [Canada] and CHARLIE JADE [Canada/South Africa].)

I just did a quick check for ReGENESIS, and at the usual suspect public sites there are season 3&4 seeds, not very well trafficked, so you'll have to be patient through the process. At two of the better private sites, there are, respectively, a Complete Series seed and individual seeds for each season, that are more actively trafficked. Which is pretty good for a Canadian show that ended in 2008. More than that I probably shouldn't say in a public forum — and again, I can't say I'm an advocate of the less ethical use — but in *extremis*, for lack of another source, you can *usually* find what you're looking for if you sail into skull-and-crossbones waters, especially if the TV series in question had enough popularity to last several seasons. Your mileage may vary.